# SCSS file is not being applied to my HTML webpage

Tags: html, css, sass

I created a simple network of HTML pages styled with SCSS but the SCSS rules aren't being applied!
Heres how my SCSS file looks like:

```
    //SCSS variables
$Heading-size: 60px;
$Mobile-Heading-size: 40px;
$Mobile-Body-Size: 30px;
$Defualt-background: rgba(149, 149, 243, 0.616);
//SCSS Inheritance and .class selector
.nav{
    @extend h1;
}
img{
    width: 250px;
}
body {
    color: black;
    background-color: $Defualt-background;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;

    //SCSS Nesting
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        size: $Heading-size;
        color: tomato;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: $Defualt-background;
    }
}
table {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    th {
        border-width: 4px;
    }
    td {
        border-width: 2px;
    }
}
//responsive @media query
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
    h1 {
        size: $Mobile-Heading-size;
}
body {
//The background is a test to see if it works :)
$Defualt-background: orange;
background-color: $Defualt-background;
size: $Mobile-Body-Size
}
}
```

And this is how I linked it to my html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/style.css">
```

Just to be clear im linking the CSS generated by my compiler not the original SCSS!

Comment: How do you know the CSS isn't applied? Do you have an error in the console like 404?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/style.css">` - this doesn't tell us anything if we don't know your directory structure. Also, `size: $Mobile-Body-Size` - `size` isn't an attribute. I think you mean `font-size`. There's no reason to declare your `$Defualt-background` variable in your body tag. **Edit**: It looks like you are using `size` several places.

Comment: Did you disable the browser cache? e.g. on Chrome: Ctrl+Shift+I > Network > Disable cache